# node version manager: curl: (56) GnuTLS recv error (-54): Error in the pull function

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, curl, nvm

This is the output i am getting while running command `nvm install 4.6.0` in my ubuntu 16.04.

```
###############################################################           88.0%
curl: (56) GnuTLS recv error (-54): Error in the pull function.
Binary download from https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.6.0/node-v4.6.0-linux-x64.tar.xz failed, trying source.
grep: /home/swap/.nvm/.cache/bin/node-v4.6.0-linux-x64/node-v4.6.0-linux-x64.tar.xz: No such file or directory
Provided file to checksum does not exist.
Binary download failed, trying source.
####
```

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this issue and i believe it must be an issue with some GNU or curl

The way i was able to install nodejs was using node version manager

Step1

```
Run either:
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.5/install.sh | bash
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.5/install.sh | bash
```

Use either wget or curl

step2

close current terminal and open another

```
nvm ls //should show if you have nodejs previous versions if none itll indicate
```

Step3:
Install latest version of nodejs by today its version 8

```
nvm install v8.6.0
```

check the latest version and replace the numbers

Now nodejs should be installed

```
node -v
npm -v
```